# Broken image when serving it over HTTP

Tags: python, wsgiref

I came across a problem reading image files (.png, .jpg, .jpeg ...) where I get the following error in the terminal: UnicodeDecodeError: the 'utf-8' codec cannot decode the 0x89 byte in position 0 : invalid starting byte. I thought I had solved the problem just by declaring o_file = open ("cloud.png", "rb") because I no longer receive the error in the terminal but an error in viewing the file (cloud.png) according to the example below:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def hello_world_app(environ, start_response):

    i_file = open("cloud.png", "rb")
    o_file = i_file.read()

    status = '200 OK'  # HTTP Status
    headers = [("Content-type", "image/png; charset=utf-8")]
    start_response(status, headers)

    # The returned object is going to be printed
    return [str(o_file).encode("utf-8")]

with make_server('', 8000, hello_world_app) as httpd:

    print(
        'Running Kosmos Application\n'
        'Browser Access - http://127.0.0.1:8000\n'
        'Crl+c for flow command or Crl+z for stop'
    )
    # Serve until process is killed
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

[image]

I would like to know why this happens and how do I solve this problem without using a third party module? Below is a preview of the file normally opened without the use of python:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be severely confused about what character encodings are useful for.

Probably read Joel Spolsky's [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) before you try to read the rest of this answer.

You are replacing the binary PNG data with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when you `encode` it. You should not be manipulating the data at all; just read it into a buffer, and send it to the client. End of story.

```py
def hello_world_app(environ, start_response):
    with open("cloud.png", "rb") as i_file:
        o_file = i_file.read()

    status = '200 OK'  # HTTP Status
    headers = [("Content-type", "image/png")]  # no ; charset here!
    start_response(status, headers)

    return [o_file]
```